# Maven: Force Jersey to use specific artifact version

Tags: maven, jersey, jena

I have a Maven repository where I load Jena TDB 0.9.3 (which depends on Jena ARQ 2.9.3), Jersey 1.8 and [RMOnto 1.0](http://semantic.cs.put.poznan.pl/maven/put/semantic/RMOnto/1.0/). The point is, as you expected, to do some analysis on semantic datasets.

It looks like RMOnto has ARQ 2.8.7 built in, as in "hardwired". There isn't any explicit dependency in its pom file, yet the jar file contains a `ARQ.class`. It's very tricky because you won't notice it with Maven Enforcer Plugin and the like.

It looks like this causes Jersey to use RMOnto's ARQ version instead of the one defined in pom.xml. Here is a [minimal example](https://github.com/prayerslayer/Jersey-ARQ-RMOnto). When you run the test (checks whether or not ARQ.VERSION equals 2.9.3), it succeeds. When you build the project and deploy it on a Tomcat 7, you should see 2.8.7 as output.

- Is this behaviour expected and why?
- How could one force Jersey to use ARQ 2.9.3?
- In case it's not possible, could one isolate RMOnto to use 2.8.7 while the rest of the source uses 2.9.3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You should define the ARQ 2.9.3 first in the dependencies list. By doing that you force your build to use that specific version. The dependency order is relevant when choosing what artifact to use.

---

### Update

OK, I understand what the problem is.

- The RMOnto jar is obviously shaded according to the pom: http://semantic.cs.put.poznan.pl/maven/put/semantic/RMOnto/1.0/RMOnto-1.0.pom.
- Tomcat 7 loads the jars in `WEB-INF/lib` in an undefined order. This means that even if you define ARQ 2.9.3 to be first in your dependencies it will not be the case when the application is run in Tomcat. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html
- Good thing is that Tomcat always look in `WEB-INF/classes` before `WEB-INF/lib` for dependencies.

So what you can do as a work around is to make sure that the ARQ 2.9.3 version is added to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. This can be done using the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
                                <version>2.9.3</version>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <excludes>**/META-INF/</excludes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Your war as well as your exploded war will now contain all the classes from ARQ 2.9.3 in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. They will be loaded before any jar-file that is in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

**NB:** I have not tested this on Tomcat but I cannot see that it would not work.

**NB2:** This is a hack. Best thing would be to remove the ARQ packages out of the RMOnto jar.

Comment: It is defined first: [pom.xml](https://github.com/prayerslayer/Jersey-ARQ-RMOnto/blob/master/pom.xml) (jena-tdb 0.9.3). Or did you mean "define explicitly"?

Comment: Define ARQ 2.9.3 explicitly first in dependencies. Not talking about the jena-tbd.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't help. See the [updated pom](https://github.com/prayerslayer/Jersey-ARQ-RMOnto/blob/master/pom.xml). I ran (in this order) maven clean, update maven artifacts, clean & build project, maven install. Twice.

The tests still succeed (which means that ARQ version in test environment is 2.9.3), but deployed on a Tomcat it shows me 2.8.7 (not desired).

Comment: As you can see [here](http://semantic.cs.put.poznan.pl/maven/put/semantic/RMOnto/1.0/RMOnto-1.0.pom) they seem to have used the [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). The Shade plugin takes all the dependencies and put in an Über jar. That is of course the problem you have at hand.

Comment: Yes, we got the source code from the maintainers. There we moved the ARQ dependency to its POM file. We included their whole project in ours (multi maven project). The jar is still shaded, but we're able to choose the version. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You should file a defect report against RMOnto. Hard-wiring library code into a jar, instead of including it as a dependency you can manage in the POM, is definitely a bad idea that the code maintainer should fix.

Answer (score 1):

If the files have been copied directly to the RMOnto .jar, the behaviour is expected.

In that case, I'd say the best bet is to hardcode it away, aka remove the ARQ files directly from the package. Opening up the RMOnto-1.0.jar package one can see arq files in the arq folder. What you'd need to do is open up the jar file (it's just a .zip), remove the ARQ files from there, store the edited RMOnto package in your version control / repository and refer to the edited package from there. Also, you'd need to add excludes statement to your pom for the old version of ARC and keep the dependency to the new version.

If you feel like it, it would be also good practice to remove the other dependencies that haven't been mentioned in the RMOnto's pom file, then add them in the RMOnto pom file (and rebuild, if you have the source code). This way Maven mechanism would be aware of them. The file seems to contain a lot of dependencies like this, which will cause headaches in the future.